# Alphabetically arranged to not alphabetical in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, string-concatenation

I have to make a program that would concatinate strings with same initials but the problem is if I input

> example input: soda, toast, salt, tea

the output would always be:

> output: saltsoda, teatoast

but the output that i want is:

> sodasalt, toasttea

How do i remain the function of my codes and the only change is not make it alphabetically arranged?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[100][100], str[1000], temp[100];
    int n, i, j;
    char *ptr, *ptr1, letter;

    printf("Enter how many arrays: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &str1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(strcasecmp(str1[i], str1[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, str1[i]);
                strcpy(str1[i], str1[j]);
                strcpy(str1[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            if (tolower(str1[i][0]) != tolower(letter))
            {
                printf(",");
            }
        }
        {
            printf("%s", str1[i]);
            letter = str1[i][0];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to sort on the first letter only, and keep the relative ordering of the words in the input.

One possible way to do it (just off the top of my head) could be to sort in multiple passes and using *indexes* instead.

Once you have read the input you create an array of indexes for the `str1` array. It will start out ordered (i.e. `indexarray[0]` will be referencing `str1[0]` and therefore have the value `0`, etc.). Then you sort using this index array instead, swapping indexes in it (i.e. you swap `indexarray[i]` and `indexarray[j]`).

When that's done you should have basically what you already have. But then you do *another* pass of sorting, this time sorting the index array itself, but not a full sort, only within a range where the first letter of the words are the same (i.e. `str1[indexarray[i]][0] == str1[indexarray[j]][0]`).

---

Some example: Using the same input as in your question then `indexarray` would look like this

```
indexarray[0] == 0  // soda
indexarray[1] == 1  // toast
indexarray[2] == 2  // salt
indexarray[3] == 3  // tea
```

After the first sorting pass it would look like

```
indexarray[0] == 2  // salt
indexarray[1] == 0  // soda
indexarray[2] == 3  // tea
indexarray[3] == 1  // toast
```

Then after the second pass, where you do multiple partial sorts of the index array (each partial sort will sort only for a specific first letter of the word), then the array would look like

```
indexarray[0] == 0  // soda
indexarray[1] == 2  // salt
indexarray[2] == 1  // toast
indexarray[3] == 3  // tea
```

---

Like I said, this is just of the top of my head, and I don't have any code (real or pseudo) to show, but hopefully it could be enough for some ideas.